# Using ClearQuest for a inventory management application

Tags: clearquest

Has anyone used IBM Rational ClearQuest to create schemas for a inventory management or similar application?  We're being "asked" to use this tool because it's already bought and paid for to web-enabled some legacy systems but I think it's completely the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

I am with you on this one, while ClearQuest is a customizable work flow engine, using it for a bunch of "stateless" records like inventory seems a bit off. Is there more to it than that or is your interest simple in tracking inventory ?

If so I would argue, that while it is possible and the upfront setup cost of effort, and since you already own it now, would be low you may end up paying for that simplicity now with a system that is not what you wanted in a year or two years, or when you reach a few million records and it starts to crawl...

Answer (score 1):

Does your Inventory Mgt system requires a web interface, and a customized workflow for your Admin / Asset mgt pple to work with?

If yes, then CQ makes sense. Otherwise, if you are only looking at a dump storage area for your records, a MS Access may even be better for the job.

Comment: I disagree that CQ makes sense for this application, even if their need is for a web interface and a customized workflow. Using CQ for this goes way beyond a square peg in a round hole, more like fitting a live ravenous bear into a round hole.

Comment: u r right in your description, and I totally agree. However, we do not know what "scale" of an Inventory application he is talking about, if its huge and involves complicated workflow, I still think CQ is one of the tools that could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

???

Clearquest is a bug/issue tracking system, albeit a highly customizable one. But there are limits to what you can do with a bug tracking system.

Answer (score 0):

It's definately possible but I can't see how you'd get the most benifit from Clearquests functionality (state transition being the main one). I guess you could create stateless records for each item type location etc and then import your legacy data using the import tool. If you already have a developer assigned to Clearquest it might be a faster solution than buying in something or using something open source. The arguement against would be no kind of automated discovery or integrated management.